# How to use Python api respose inseredt to questdb

Tags: python, insert, response, questdb

How can i get Python script to insert this to quest DB

b"[{'timeStamp': '2019-02-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1794.0}, {'timeStamp': '2019-03-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1486.0}, {'timeStamp': '2019-04-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1123.0}, {'timeStamp': '2019-05-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1022.0}, {'timeStamp': '2019-06-01T00:00:00', 'value': 840.0}, {'timeStamp': '2019-07-01T00:00:00', 'value': 810.0}, {'timeStamp': '2019-08-01T00:00:00', 'value': 814.0}, {'timeStamp': '2019-09-01T00:00:00', 'value': 902.0}, {'timeStamp': '2019-10-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1157.0}, {'timeStamp': '2019-11-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1426.0}, {'timeStamp': '2019-12-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1705.0}, {'timeStamp': '2020-01-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1617.0}, {'timeStamp': '2020-02-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1520.0}, {'timeStamp': '2020-03-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1540.0}, {'timeStamp': '2020-04-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1205.0}, {'timeStamp': '2020-05-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1185.0}, {'timeStamp': '2020-06-01T00:00:00', 'value': 923.0}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-01T00:00:00', 'value': 998.0}, {'timeStamp': '2020-08-01T00:00:00', 'value': 939.0}, {'timeStamp': '2020-09-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1055.0}, {'timeStamp': '2020-10-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1251.0}, {'timeStamp': '2020-11-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1367.0}, {'timeStamp': '2020-12-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1691.0}, {'timeStamp': '2021-01-01T01:00:00', 'value': 2147.0}, {'timeStamp': '2021-02-01T01:00:00', 'value': 2067.0}, {'timeStamp': '2021-03-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1846.0}, {'timeStamp': '2021-04-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1625.0}, {'timeStamp': '2021-05-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1354.0}, {'timeStamp': '2021-06-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1099.0}, {'timeStamp': '2021-07-01T00:00:00', 'value': 987.0}, {'timeStamp': '2021-08-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1188.0}, {'timeStamp': '2021-09-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1259.0}, {'timeStamp': '2021-10-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1435.0}, {'timeStamp': '2021-11-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1697.0}, {'timeStamp': '2021-12-01T01:00:00', 'value': 2483.0}, {'timeStamp': '2022-01-01T01:00:00', 'value': 2409.0}, {'timeStamp': '2022-02-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1973.0}, {'timeStamp': '2022-03-01T01:00:00', 'value': 1998.0}, {'timeStamp': '2022-04-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1702.0}, {'timeStamp': '2022-05-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1270.0}, {'timeStamp': '2022-06-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1128.0}, {'timeStamp': '2022-07-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1012.0}, {'timeStamp': '2022-08-01T00:00:00', 'value': 953.0}, {'timeStamp': '2022-09-01T00:00:00', 'value': 1078.0}, {'timeStamp': '2022-10-04T00:00:00', 'value': 953.4}]"

I test but get only could not parse measurement, INCOMPLETE_TAG

```
def main_request(extractUrl,headers): 
        #using requests to call API data 
        r = requests.get(extractUrl,headers=headers) 
        #returning data in json format 
        return r.json() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while 1==1:
            # Get data from the API variable calling main function 
            data_month = main_request(monthUrl, headers=headersAPI)
            
            # creating a dataframe using pandas 
            data = str(data_month['measurements']) 
            
            # Send data to QuestDB
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
            #sock.sendall(data)
            sock.sendall(('measurements,'+data).encode())

            sleep(2)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are ingesting the data in the wrong format.

QuestDB supports the InfluxDB line protocol for ingesting data.

The following format is expected:

`table_name,symbolset columnset timestamp\n`

More information about ILP and questDB can be found here: https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/ilp/overview/

They also provide examples how to use their python package for ingesting data: https://questdb.io/docs/develop/insert-data#influxdb-line-protocol

Comment: Trying to understand but this is my fist time. Only want the response to go in to two tables. timeStamp and value.                                                                                                                                             timeStamp   value kWt
2019-02-01T01:00:00 1794.0
2019-03-01T01:00:00 1486.0
2019-04-01T00:00:00 1123.0
2019-05-01T00:00:00 1022.0
2019-06-01T00:00:00 840.0
2019-07-01T00:00:00 810.0
2019-08-01T00:00:00 814.0
2019-09-01T00:00:00 902.0
2019-10-01T00:00:00 1157.0